# Using variables in a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This line   $(''+fullId+'')   is giving me problems. I've created an array in a different function that gets the #id's of all the inputs in the DOM.

Now with this function i'm trying to create a blur and focus jQuery function. I've set the variable fullId to prepend the '"#' and append the '"' to the variable name, but how do I get it to work?

$(''+fullId+'') is not doing the trick and neither does $(fullId)

```
function focusBlur () {

        var inputId = 0;
        var fullId = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<size; i++) {

            inputId = arr.shift();
            fullId = "\"#"+inputId+"\"";


            $(''+fullId+'').blur(function() {

            });
            $(''+fullId+'').focus(function() {

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $("#" + inputId)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the double quotes.  Just use:

```
fullId = "#" + inputId;
```

instead of:

```
fullId = "\"#"+inputId+"\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(fullId).blur(function() {});`

Ah, yeah, I missed adding the double-quotes.  They're not necessary when the id is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

could you try

```
var fullId = "#"+inputId;

$(fullId).blur(function() {

        });
$(fullId).focus(function() {

        });
```